# ReactJS: setState on object of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have in my state:

```
state = {
  validationButton: {
   button1: false
   }
}


componentDidMount(){
//....
this.check(1)
this.check(2)
}

check(Number){
 let today = new Date()
 // I call my api to see if exists document with the number
  db.get(`${Number}:${today}`)
  .then( (doc) => {
    //after that I found document:
    // * this is what I would to do *
    this.setState((this.state.validationButton[`button${Number}`] = true))
})
}
```

But I receive the error message:

> Invariant Violation: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.

How can I do to set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` should get an object to set:

```
this.setState({ validationButton: {[`button${Number}`]: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do:

```js
this.setState({ validationButton: {[`button${Number}`]: true });
```